# node.js looping on a spawn call

Tags: node.js

I am trying to start a long running program that gives lots of output to sdtout. I was trying to use the method below to read data on intervals.

```
s    = spawn('blah_long_running_expect.pl --device server');
setInterval( function (){   
  s.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
     console.log("herehere");})
},1000);

}
```

This is part of a http server instance...there is a createserver somewhere before that. My eventual idea is to use response.write to output to screen

I'm getting the below error right now. I'm wondering if this setinterval way of reading lines is completely wrong?

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. 
Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace: 
    at Socket.<anonymous> (events.js:126:17)
    at Timer.callback (/tmp/requestHandlers.js:12:17)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

s.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
     console.log("herehere");})
},1000);

The `.on` call adds an event listener. What you want to do instead is something like this.

```
s = spawn('blah_long_running_expect.pl --device server');
var dd = "";
s.stdout.on('data', function(d) {
  console.log('some data : ' + d);
  dd += d;
});
s.stdout.on('end', function() {
  console.log('end');
});
setInterval( function (){   
  console.log(dd);
  dd = "";
},1000);
```

Comment: Thanks. So I tried that. Now I run around and around in the setInterval function. but I get no data for s.stdout. From what you were saying I would have assumed the event listener and setInerval would continue to respectively listen on stdout and print output on an interval if there is any.

Comment: @evolution what's it supposed to is append data to a local variable then print the data and reset it every second. I did make the foolish assumption that the data outputted by your perl is a string.

Comment: Actualy for now i'm even putting 'find /' in for spawn.

Comment: OK. It works. It seems if you put 'find /' all as one as first spawn argument nothing happens. I moved it to be spawn('find',['/']) and this started to work.

Answer (score 0):

With your code, it is adding a new event listener every second. You don't need to worry about splitting the output into chunks; Node.js takes care of that, and that is exactly what 'data' event is for.